# _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?) sqlalchemy

Tags: python, csv, flask

```
class productions(db.Model):
    """Model for the stations table"""
    __tablename__ = 'production'
    id_pro = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    prix = db.Column(db.Float)
```

i have to recover the data from my csv sheet and add it to the database with sqlalchemy
if you have ideas to propose to me, thank you in advance

````
@app.route('/uploader', methods=['Get', 'POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_pro = request.files['production']
        print(file_pro)
        f = file_pro.read()
        csv_data = csv.reader(f)
        for line in csv_data:
            print(line)
            productions.insert().values(id_pro=line[0],name = line[1], prix = line[2] )
    return redirect(url_for('prod'))```
````